# SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using MongoDB + Node.js to create an app, but I am receiving an error for this code:

### company.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var companySchema = Schema({

    creator: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User' 
    },
    name: String,
    description: String,
    categories: [String],
    website: String,
    address: String,
    statuses: [{ 
        date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }, 
        status: String 
    }],
    friends: [{ 
        name: String, 
        description: String 
    }],
    priority: Number,
    isActive: Boolean,
    contacts: [{ 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'ContactPerson' 
    }],
    createdOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Company', companySchema);
```

### api.js

```
api.route('/company')

    .post(function(req, res) {

        var company = new Company({
                creator: req.decoded.id,
                name: req.body.name,
                description: req.body.description,
                categories: req.body.categories,
                website: req.body.website,
                address: req.body.address,
                friends.name: req.body.friendName,
                statuses: { status: "New Company" },
                priority: req.body.priority,
        });

        company.save(function(err, newCompany) {

            if(err) {
                res.send(err);
                return
            }
            res.json({ message: "New company has been created!" });
        });
    })
```

### Error

friends.name: req.body.friendName,

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

I also tried with friend['name'] but the result was the same: SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Please tell me where is my mistake

Comment: When you want to use a dot in a property name, enclose that property name with `'` or `"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var company = new Company({
        creator: req.decoded.id,
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        categories: req.body.categories,
        website: req.body.website,
        address: req.body.address,
        friends: {
            name: req.body.friendName
        },
        statuses: { status: "New Company" },
        priority: req.body.priority,
});
```

or:

```
var company = new Company({
        creator: req.decoded.id,
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        categories: req.body.categories,
        website: req.body.website,
        address: req.body.address,
        'friends.name': req.body.friendName,
        statuses: { status: "New Company" },
        priority: req.body.priority,
});
```

depend on what you're after.

Comment: Thank you, both of them are working, but here the second problem appear: the target data is array and the data is not inserted.

Comment: @Vintila then try to use `friends: [{ name: req.body.friendName }],`

Answer (score 0):

Use latest version of nvm and then run it

Write **`nvm use version 16`**.

And then write: **`npx nodemon index`**.